# Iteration: Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, c++11, set

I am trying to iterate through a set of strings, declared here:

`std::set<std::string>aB;`, and here `std::set<int>::iterator iter;`

The problem is here:

```
for(iter = aB.begin(); iter != aB.end(); ++iter) {
    std::cout << *iter << n;
```

In theory, this should print out the contents of aB (available Buildings), but instead, it gives two errors:

> error: no viable overloaded '=' -> [ for(iter = aB.begin(); ]

and

> error: invalid operands to binary expression -> [ std::set< int >::iterator ]

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why do you use a set-of-strings iterator on a set-of-ints? o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
std::set<int>::iterator iter;
```

use

```
std::set<std::string>::iterator iter;
```

Since you are using C++11, you can also use:

```
for(auto iter = aB.begin(); iter != aB.end(); ++iter) {
    std::cout << *iter << n;
```

Better yet, use the range for construct:

```
for(auto const& item : aB) {
    std::cout << item << n;
```

Comment: In C++11 there is no need to have an iterator at all, you can directly use a range based loop: `for (const auto& value : aB)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use an **iterator** of your original **set's type** . So in your case it would be:

```
std::set<std::string>::iterator iter;
```